# Twig - binary negation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, dql

I have the following code inside the twig template file:

```
<th class="head0"><a href="{{ url('product_list', {'page': page, 'sort': "productId", 'order': order}) }}">ID</a></th>
```

Order is a binary integer value (0/1). What I wanna do is to change the value of that variable everytime I click the link. I also cannot use negation in the controller, because it would change that value everytime I click any link redirecting to this specific route.

Is there a way to do this in twig?

Comment: You have several questions in one topic, split it.

Comment: Uh, ok, I edited the post :P

Comment: You want to change `order` in your twig and it be synchronised with your DB? Or what do you want? I didn't understand.

Comment: I want to negate the order slug...so if it's currently 0, I want to pass it as 1. And the other way.

Comment: What's the matter with a simple `{{ order ? 0 : 1 }}`?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve shouldn't be in Twig file. You can only render the initial values with twig. As you said you want the link to respond to user's click. There's two classic ways to do that:

1. this can be a Javascript code that respond to click and send an ajax request to your
   controller. Then you can persist it or do whatever you want with it.
   This is the recommended way.
2. The click redirect you to a new page and the controller that serves that route has the logic you want that is toggling a value or checking a status.